# How to debug Axios on iOS when getting network error?

Tags: javascript, ios, axios

I tested my application finally in iOS and found out that AXIOS don't work on Chrome and Firefox.

I don't know much about iOS debug tools but I used chrome://inspect on my iPad and can read:

> Error: Network Error

I simplified the code and always get this error on iOS while it is working fine on the desktop browsers.

```
axios.get('/request' )
.then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

My iOS browsers don't have a JavaScript console that can show details on the objects. I don't know how to debug because there are no issues on desktop browsers. The backend has empty logfile, so it may not send out any GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this problem but don't understand:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://example.com";  // my correct domain name
```

Removing this line that included my domain solved the issue.

Why did't it work only on iOS (I didn't tested Android) while still working on desktop browsers?